# Google App Engine Python Simple Question

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine the datastore creates a new entry every time you assign it a value. What I Am trying to do is store a simple variable x. When a function is called 1 is added to x and it is stored again (and some other simple stuff that i have the code written already). How would i achieve this is python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to keep a counter.  [This tutorial](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) is good for using "sharded counters", that is, a counter that not only works like you expect, but also is much more efficient to update, since you won't have as much contention for the counter object.